# give an example of a vector field perpendicular at every point

Tags: calculus, vector-fields

I need to give an example of a vector field $F(x,y)$ in 2-space.

I have $G$...

$$G = (x+y)i + (1+y^2)j$$

I need to find $F$ that is perpendicular to $G$ at every point.

I know the dot product need to be 0 between $F$ and $G$ but I have no idea how to solve this with vector fields, only with vectors. Can someone show me how this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about $F=-(1+y^2)\hat \imath+(x+y)\hat\jmath $?